# Is there an Eclipse hotkey to switch tabs in the same way a browser switches tabs?

Tags: eclipse, ide, tabs, hotkeys

In other words, I want to use CMD+2 to switch to the 2nd tab from the left directly, like I can do in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse you can switch between tabs with the command <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> for the next one and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> for going back.

To switch to a index of a tab is at the moment not possible

Comment: The answer disappoints me, but it answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

CTRL E and CTRL F6 are only ones I know

Comment: want to explain why these were voted down? the answer above is essentially the same

Answer (score -1):

- Go to *Window > Preferences > General > Keys*
- In the search field, type 'next tab'
- Down in the Binding field you can assign whatever keystroke you want, but be sure and pay attention if there are any conflicts
- Search again for 'previous tab'
- Assign to binding again